# PTIJ: What's wrong with how the Ba'al Koreh pronounces Haman's name?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Every time the Ba'al Koreh makes a mistake, those present clop on the Bimah once at the end of the Passuk, to signal to the reader that he messed up. So what's wrong with how the Ba'al Koreh pronounces Haman's name?

Why does everyone bang whenever he reads "Haman"? Are we all saying it wrong?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I always wondered why we dont 'klop' zeresh, who was even worse that haman. It was her idea to  build the high scaffold and to find a 'beam' long enough which originally came from the ark she agreed to use the one from her house, which had to be demolished within a few hours. In shoshanas yaakov we do remember her. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IGhA8b5Xxw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to the question is that those who 'klop' are so drunk not to know the difference between cursing haman and blessing mordechai and really think the reader is mistaken about saying all the bad things about haman and it should be saying mordechai there.You will always see the ones who cant stop 'klopping' are the most drunk. This minhag is mentioned in r'mo and he adds one must not be mevatel it or laugh at it. According to my reasonlng it is quite simple because if they did, it would stop people becoming shikkur being ashamed afterwards when they 'klop' by mistake, and being shikkur is a great mitsva. One could add even that is why everyone should 'klop' not to shame those who are not shikkur, like we find many things, and there is nothing worse than not being shikkur on purim. And it being such a big mistake it deserves a lot of 'klopping'. Therefore it is wrong what some readers repeating 'haman' again after the 'klopping' ,making the mistake once is bad enough.

Comment: since with zeresh there can never be a mistake no 'klopping' there. It seems one can never mistake her for esther

Comment: אמר רבא מיחייב איניש לבסומי בפוריא עד דלא ידע בין ארור המן לברוך מרדכי it doesnt mention zeresh and esther am trying to think of a good reason why they cant be mistaken..It will come to me.

Comment: Maybe because both are not Jewish names one can mix them up easily so one is not considered shikkur enough by just mixing two non Jewish names and it needs one to be Jewish as well.

Comment: Or it says one should 'not ''know'' the difference. Knowledge comes from the tree of knowledge which the torah calls 'homon's tree' hamin ho'ets. That is why on purim one should forget 'knowledge' and it being homon's tree we only forget 'homon'. It can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

As a *ba'al Kri'ah*, I think I need to correct you regarding protocol.

During the Shabbat Torah reading, nobody clops (what are you? A horse??) People just yell at you on how to read it, and usually, it's more than one person doing the yelling. Yes, a rude annoyance, but, that's for a separate M.Y. question.

On Purim, they're not clopping for the mistake. Again, protocol for a mistake is not to clop. The clopping is to signal to the listeners that they may begin making noise with the groggers and stamp their feet. Many people fall asleep or are otherwise not paying close attention, so they need a loud reminder.

Comment: If they are not paying close attention they have to listen again. It isnt only the word haman one has to listen to

Comment: @interested You're over-analyzing. They probably heard the word "Haman", but, may not be paying attention to when to start making noise, or even if they should at all. In many minyanim, people just want to hear Megilla quickly and get home to eat, so they may not be drowning out Haman at all, at least not for every one of them.